How to solve this inequality problem that contains a parameter?

Find the range of $x$ such that,
$|\log_{\sqrt{a}}x-2|-|\log_ax-2|<2$

The answer is when $a>1, a^{-2}<x<a^2$ ; when $0<a<1, a^2<x<x^{-2}$.
I approach this problem in the following two ways but none of them give me the right answer.
First way:
$|\log_{\sqrt{a}}x-2|-|\log_ax-2|<2$
$\Rightarrow |\frac{\log_ax}{\log_a{\sqrt{a}}}-2|-|\log_ax-2|<2$
$\Rightarrow |2\log_{a}x-2|-|\log_ax-2|<2 \cdots (1)$
Consider three cases:$\log_ax > 2, 1<\log_ax\leq2, 1\leq \log_ax$
we can conclude $a<x<a^2$
Second way:
From $(1)$ we let $\log_ax = y$
$\Rightarrow (2y-2)^2<(2+|y-2|)^2$
$\Rightarrow 3y^2-4y-4<4|y-2|$
$\Rightarrow (3y-2)^2(y+2)^2<16(y-2)^2$
$\Rightarrow (9y^2+12y-12)^2(y-2)^2<0$
$\Rightarrow (3y-2)(y+2)(y-2)^2<0$
$\Rightarrow -2<\log_ax<\frac{2}{3}$
$\Rightarrow a^{-2}<x<a^{\frac{2}{3}}$
Can anyone tell me the issue with my problem, why both way come up with different answer, and how to solve it?

It can't be, $\log_{\sqrt{a}}x = \frac{\log_{a}x}{\log_{a}\sqrt{a}}  = \frac{\log_{a}x}{\frac{1}{2}} = 2\log_{a}x$.

Following your second approach, you have been correct up to
$$3 {y}^{2} - 4 y - 4 < 4 \left| y - 2 \right|.$$
In the your next step, however,
$$\color{red}{3 {y}^{2} - 4 y - 4 \neq \left( 3 y - 2 \right) \left( y + 2 \right);}$$
rather,
$$\color{blue}{3 {y}^{2} - 4 y - 4 = \left( 3 y + 2 \right) \left( y - 2 \right).}$$
So
$$\left( 3 y + 2 \right) \left( y - 2 \right) < 4 \left| y - 2 \right|.$$
If $y > 2$, then $\left( 3 y + 2 \right) \cdot 1 < 4 \cdot 1$, so $y < 2 / 3$. If $y < 2$, then $\left( 3 y + 2 \right) \cdot \left( - 1 \right) < 4 \cdot 1$, so $y > - 2$. Now, plug these back:
$$\left| 2 y - 2 \right| < 2 + \left| y - 2 \right|.$$
If $y = - 2$, then
$$\left| 2 \cdot \left( - 2 \right) - 2 \right| = 6 = 2 + \left| \left( - 2 \right) - 2 \right|.$$
If $y = 2 / 3$, then
$$\left| 2 \cdot \frac {2}{3} - 2 \right| = \frac {2}{3} < \frac {10}{3} = 2 + \left| \frac {2}{3} - 2 \right|.$$
So $y < 2 / 3$ is spurious. We therefore conclude that $- 2 < y = \log_{a} \left( x \right) < 2$, or equivalently, ${a}^{- 2} < x < {a}^{2}$ if $a > 1$. If $0 < a < 1$, then ${a}^{2} < x < {a}^{- 2}$.
